# Gaussian Blur with Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, blur, gaussian

I am working on Gaussian blur, and in order to speed the algorithm execution, I was thinking about separating image into parts and apply threading for each part.
Unfortunately, the algorithm does the opposite, it just slows things down. As I am new to threading I wonder if it is something I am doing wrong or the whole concept is wrong.

Some information about my Gaussian algorithm, I am using half-kernel trick as both left and right hand side of Gaussian kernel are the same. The main method is RunGaussian, but threading is performed in GaussianWithThreading method.

Important notes: I am limited by mono framework and cannot use Tasks. This is not the final version, it is quick mock-up version prepared for testing how threading performs.

The algorithm concept:

1) Take a picture, convert to grayscale get an array of values (not included here).

2) Divide the array into segments based on number of threads used.

3) Each thread performs calculations on x-dimension for selected values in input array updating x_values global array.

4) After 3) is done, each thread performs calculations on y-dimension for selected values in the x_values global array.

5) When 4) is done, convert new grayscale values into a texture (not included here).

```
public class Gaussian
{
  private float [] colors;
  private float [] x_values;
  private float [] y_values;
  private int width = 2000;
  private int height = 1900;
  private int thread_pool;

  public float[] RunGaussian(int number_of_threads, float [] colors, float [] kernel)
  {
    this.colors = colors;
    x_values = new float[width*height];
    y_values = new float[width*height];
    thread_pool = number_of_threads;
    return GaussianWithThreading(kernel,kernel);
  }

  private float[] GaussianWithThreading(float [] kernel_x, float [] kernel_y)
  {
    Thread [] threads = new Thread[thread_pool];
    int per_thread = colors.Length/thread_pool;

    //x-dimension
    for (var i = 0; i<thread_pool;i++)
    {
      int start = (i == 0)? 0 : per_thread * i;
      int stop = (i == thread_pool)? colors.Length-1 : (per_thread * (i+1))-1;
      threads[i] = new Thread(()=> ApplyWithThread(0,kernel_x, kernel_y, colors, start, stop));
      threads[i].Start();
    }

    bool stillActive = true;
    while (stillActive)
    {
      int count = 0;
      foreach (var t in threads)
      {
        if (!t.IsAlive) count++;
      }
      if (count == thread_pool) stillActive = false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i<thread_pool;i++)
    {
      int start = (i == 0)? 0 : per_thread * i;
      int stop = (i == thread_pool)? colors.Length-1 : (per_thread * (i+1))-1;
      threads[i] = new Thread(()=> ApplyWithThread(1,kernel_x, kernel_y, x_values,start, stop));
      threads[i].Start();
    }

    stillActive = true;
    while (stillActive)
    {
      int count = 0;
      foreach (var t in threads)
      {
        if (!t.IsAlive) count++;
      }
      if (count == thread_pool) stillActive = false;
    }

    return y_values;
  }

  private void ApplyWithThread(int dimension, float [] kernel_x, float [] kernel_y, float [] values, int start_point, int finish_point)
  {
    //x-dimension
    if (dimension == 0)
    {
      for (int i = start_point; i<=finish_point;i++)
      {
        int x = i%width;
        int y = i/width;
        int y_cor = y * width;

        float val = values[i] * kernel_x[0];
        for (int j = 1, n= kernel_x.Length; j<n;j++)
        {
          int previous = x - j;
          if (previous < 0) previous = 0;
          int p_pos = y_cor + previous;

          int next = x + j;
          if (next>=width) next = width-1;
          int n_pos = y_cor + next;

          val += (values[p_pos] * kernel_x[j]) + (values[n_pos] * kernel_x[j]);
        }
        x_values[i] = val;
      }
    }
    //y-dimension
    else 
    {
    for (int i = start_point; i<=finish_point;i++)
      {
        int x = i%width;
        int y = i/width;

        float val = values[i] * kernel_y[0];
        for (int j = 1, n= kernel_y.Length; j<n;j++)
        {
          int previous = y - j;
          if (previous < 0) previous = 0;
          int p_pos = previous * width + x;
          int next = y + j;
          if (next>=height) next = height-1;
          int n_pos = next * width + x;
          val += (values[p_pos] * kernel_y[j]) + (values[n_pos] * kernel_y[j]);
        }
        y_values[i] = val;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Ok, I am getting somewhere now.
I have utilized ThreadPool, ManualResetEvents and WaitHandle to make sure that all threads converge then needed.
I have also modified, as advised by **Harold**, the kernel application algorithm to utilize transpose, albeit I did not separate boundaries checking (every scenario I think about makes it more complicated then current version).
There is still some work to be done as WaitHandle only allows 64 events, forces me to use no more than 64 threads. Furthermore, when I used 63 threads I have noticed my computer to became laggy (spikes, probably due to WaitHandle), which makes me think that WaitHandle is not the best option. Sadly, I am pre .NET 4.0 and cannot use Barrier class. See the snippet below. G_Data is just struct to make it more visually appealing, I will probably ditch it (should give me some boost).

Testing data (only filter application, no texture<-> data conversion or kernel preparation):

Texture - 2048x1421

1. Kernel size: **3** at Thread count: **3** -> Time (average of 10): **84 ms**
2. Kernel size: **3** at Thread count: **63** -> Time (average of 10): **70 ms**
3. Kernel size: **64** at Thread count: **3** -> Time (average of 10): **1854 ms**
4. Kernel size: **64** at Thread count: **63** -> Time (average of 10): **1368 ms**

From results it is easily visible that for small kernel difference in number of threads is marginal but with kernel increase number of threads plays significant part (no surprise there).

```
public float[] ApplyFilter(int thread_count, float [] kernel_x, float [] kernel_y, float [] values, int width, int height)
{
    this.thread_count = thread_count;
    this.kernel_x = kernel_x;
    this.kernel_y = kernel_y;
    this.values = values;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    x_values = new float[width * height];
    y_values = new float[width * height];


    int per_thread_x = height/thread_count;
    int per_thread_y = width/thread_count;

    var events = new ManualResetEvent[thread_count];

    //apply x-pass
    for (int i = 0; i<thread_count;i++)
    {
        events[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        int start = per_thread_x * i;
        int stop =  (i==thread_count-1)? height-1: (per_thread_x * (i + 1)) - 1;
        if (stop < start) stop = start;
        int j = i;
        G_Data data = new G_Data(start, stop, width, height, values, x_values, kernel_x);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => { ApplyKernel(data); events[j].Set();});
    }
    WaitHandle.WaitAll(events);

    //apply y-pass
    for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++)
    {
        events[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        int start = per_thread_y * i;
        int stop = (i == thread_count - 1) ? width - 1 : (per_thread_y * (i + 1)) - 1;
        if (stop < start) stop = start;
        int j = i;
        G_Data data = new G_Data(start, stop, height, width, x_values, y_values, kernel_y);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => { ApplyKernel(data); events[j].Set(); });
    }

    WaitHandle.WaitAll(events);
    return y_values;
}
```

*If your are surprised to see that width/height are swapped for y-pass, it is because of array transpose operation.*


Kernel algorithm:

```
    public void ApplyKernel(object args)
    {
        G_Data input_data = (G_Data)args;
        int start = input_data.start;
        int stop = input_data.stop;
        float[] kernel = input_data.kernel;
        float[] input = input_data.input_data;
        float[] output = input_data.output_data;
        int input_width = input_data.width;
        int input_height = input_data.height;

        for (int y = start; y <= stop; y++)
        {
            int row = y * input_width;

            for (int x = 0; x < input_width; x++)
            {
                float val = input[row + x] * kernel[0];
                for (int k = 1, n = kernel.Length; k < n; k++)
                {
                    int p_x = ((x - k) < 0) ? 0 : x - k;
                    int n_x = ((x + k) >= input_width) ? input_width - 1 : x + k;
                    val += (input[row + p_x] * kernel[k]) + (input[row + n_x] * kernel[k]);
                }
                output[x * input_height + y] = val;
            }
        }
    }
```

Kernel algorithm version 2

```
public void ApplyKernel(object args)
    {
        G_Data input_data = (G_Data)args;
        int start = input_data.start;
        int stop = input_data.stop;
        float[] kernel = input_data.kernel;
        float[] input = input_data.input_data;
        float[] output = input_data.output_data;
        int input_width = input_data.width;
        int input_height = input_data.height;

        int offset = kernel.Length;
        bool is_kernel_oversized = offset >= input_width / 2;
        int right_edge_start = (is_kernel_oversized) ? offset : input_width - offset;
        int y, x;

        for (y = start; y <= stop; y++)
        {
            int row = y * input_width;

            //EDGE HANDLING

            //left edge
            for (x = 0; x < offset; x++)
            {
                float val = input[row + x] * kernel[0];
                for (int k = 1, n = kernel.Length; k < n; k++)
                {
                    int p_x = ((x - k) < 0) ? 0 : x - k;
                    val += (input[row + p_x] * kernel[k]) + (input[row + x + k] * kernel[k]);
                }
                output[x * input_height + y] = val;
            }

            //right edge
            for (x = right_edge_start; x < input_width; x++)
            {
                float val = input[row + x] * kernel[0];
                for (int k = 1, n = kernel.Length; k < n; k++)
                {
                    int n_x = ((x + k) >= input_width) ? input_width - 1 : x + k;
                    val += (input[row + x - k] * kernel[k]) + (input[row + n_x] * kernel[k]);
                }
                output[x * input_height + y] = val;
            }

            //BODY SCAN
            //if kernel is oversized there is no point in doing body scan as it was already covered by edge passes above
            if (is_kernel_oversized) continue;
            for (x = offset; x < input_width - offset; x++)
            {
                float val = input[row + x] * kernel[0];
                for (int k = 1, n = kernel.Length; k < n; k++)
                {
                    val += (input[row + x-k] * kernel[k]) + (input[row + x+k] * kernel[k]);
                }
                output[x * input_height + y] = val;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is too much junk in the actual application of the kernel (can be simplified substantially) and the way you "wait" for the threads to finish is very inefficient.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. Could you provide an example what could be simplified and what other methods could I use to make sure that x-pass is finished before y-pass is started. Cheers

Comment: You could `Join` the threads or use some other actual synchronization mechanism (maybe `ManualResetEvent`), to prevent busy-waiting. The outer loop of the convolution can loop over x/y directly, and more importantly, you can handle the case "near the edge" separately from the normal case so it is only slower when it needs to be. As an extra suggestion, it may be simpler to write back the result transposed, then you don't need separate horizontal and vertical versions.

Comment: **So**, if I understand correctly, if I use thread[i].Join() just after thread[i].Start() then I can skip IsAlive loop? **Concerning x/y separation**, does not transpose mean that I get n^2 rather than 2n case. The whole point of separation of kernels into x and y is to reduced number of fetches. **About edge handling**, yes you are right, first handling edges then rest of the pixels should give me a small boost. **But** the true bottle-neck lies in my sloppy threading as I have tested normal and this version using same kernel algorithm.

Comment: Yes, join all the threads instead of the isalive thing. I meant transposing as in just writing the result back transposed, that way the x-pass writes the result in a way such that a second x-pass effectively does an y-pass (and it also turns the result back to untransposed). So it's still 2n, but with only one piece of code that is used twice.

Comment: I have tried using Join but it did not provide any improvement (sill ~3000 ms compared to 80 non-threaded). My guess is that the true bottle-neck lies within Thread instantiation and ThreadPool should be able to alleviate this issue. Using Task would be much easier but sadly, current framework does not support them. I just wonder if whole concept makes any sense, on paper it looks great, but in reality does not seem to work. **In regards to transpose**, nice concept, either transpose on fly or whole-thing in at the end should be ok. I need to wrap my head around it and think how to do it.

Comment: I don't really get how it can be that bad, how many threads are you using?

Comment: I have tried various numbers between 3 and 1000. All come close to 3000 ms (average of 5 runs). When I went crazy and used 10000, I got ~5k ms. I am testing code using online compiler repl.it. As I am modifying the kernel protocol at the same time a can make it ThreadPool friendly. Will see the effect.

Comment: Actually it works fine for me (though using Join scales better to more threads, the busy loop already starts to lose for me if I use 4 worker threads (taking longer than 3 threads), perhaps because I have 4 cores), perhaps it is a problem with repl.it

Comment: Thanks for testing it. I will test it on my local machine and see how it compares.

Comment: So, how did that go?

Comment: I am still optimising it (did not have a lot of time past 2 days). But so far works very well. I am using ThreadPool and ManualResetEvent with WaitHandler. This limits me to 64 threads but x-pass on 2000x1900 datapoint array is almost instantaneous. It must have been repl.it issue, my guess they just simulate the environment using a single thread so any attempt at real threading fails. Once I am done with it, I will post the code and testing results.

Comment: Newest version looks good, but I am not fully satisfied. I want to push it even further, but I am limited to pre .NET 4.0 which is not ideal. I want to make it do kernel of size 16 in around 100 ms  on 2100x1400 image (now is 385). Will be though nut to crack I think. I could increase number of threads, but I want it to be compatible with old phones, so I can only utilize 2 cores, which gives me max 500 threads (according to "Internets", need to ditch WaitHandle class also).

Comment: With 2 cores, anything past 2 threads shouldn't help anyway. I'd try splitting that near-the-edge case off now though, of course it causes a bit of code bloat but it simplifies the calculation for *most* pixels

Comment: Cheers, will try to do that.

Comment: I have tested removing test boundaries from main scope and you where right. Boundary testing was consuming a lot of time. 3 thread at 64 kernel is now **down to 1405 from 1854 (24 % decrease)** and 63 thread at 64 kernel is now **down to 1071 from 1368 (22 % decrease)**. Using/No-suing G_data struct does not have an impact on time.

Comment: Can you use `Mono.Simd`?

Comment: I do not see reason why not too. As long as it is compatible with Unity and I can use it in commercial application I should be fine. Btw I will upload updated kernel application now. The code is bulkier but separating left and right edge provided better times. I have also included case when kernel is bigger than width/2 (body scan is pointless as "edge" scans already covered the whole picture).